# hipchat slash commands using localhost in the url

Tags: hipchat

Trying to create a slash command in hipchat following
https://developer.atlassian.com/hipchat/tutorials/building-a-simple-add-on-using-a-wizard

I created my own http server responding to : "http://localhost:8000/test"

However, when I fill this url in the slash command attributes the messages are not being caught in my web server

any idea why it's not working ? does the url must be public so the hipchat servers will be able to have access to ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the hipchat service needs to be able to reach out to the URL you're passing. For local development, you might want to look into something like https://ngrok.com to create a cloud-accessible endpoint. I've used that when developing custom hipchat bots and works pretty well.